# About prime geodesic cycles and deck transformations group

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, spectral-theory, covering-spaces

I'm proving theorem 2 occurring in Sunada's paper [*Riemannian coverings and isospectral manifolds*](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~ted/620F09/References/Sunada/0.pdf).
Unfortunately Sunada's quotes himself to the following paper:

*Tchbotarev’s density theorem for closed geodesics in a compact locally symmetric space of
negative curvature. Preprint.*

which I'm unable to find. Is there anybody which known the Sunada's works and can help me? Maybe such article was published with another name...

Alternatively, if there is someone which well know the theory of closed geodesic decomposition under Riemannian covering, I can try to explain the point which I not understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sunada also cited it as "Chebotarev's density theorem for closed geodesics", but I could not find this title either.

Comment: Is it perhaps related to this paper from several years later? http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2374542?sid=21106181736983&uid=3739256&uid=3739808&uid=2&uid=4